# SSVNC command line arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssl, vnc

I recently got SSVNC to connect a Windows VNC client to a Linux VNC server through a repeater with SSL encryption.

I am now trying to use SSVNC in Windows Command Prompt. What I have found so far online is that command line arguments are supported in Unix environments, but have not found the same documentation for Windows. So far the only command line argument that I have found for Windows ssvnc.exe is specifying the client, which is not adequate for what I am trying to do. In Unix, there is support for specifying a profile, so I opened one of those profile files in a text editor. This seemed like a possible option for what I am trying to do, but I am not sure if the Windows executable supports it/ haven't had success with it.

Basically what I am looking for is:
Is it possible to launch SSVNC with a batch file in Windows and have SSVNC establish an SSL connection between a Windows VNC client and Linux VNC server through a UVNC repeater?
Is it possible to launch SSVNC with a profile in Windows? This way I could specify certain settings before hand and SSVNC will handle the connection and launch a viewer.
Are there any other methods I have not thought of to make this work?

Comment: I have made some progress on this. From command prompt you can change directory to where ssvnc.exe is located and specify a profile this way: ">ssvnc.exe profile" but this defaults to the "none" option where you would select an encryption option. With the server running an SSL only option, the connection cannot be established without the client side using SSL. So now I am looking into a way to force the SSL option to be selected when ssvnc starts

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to make this work in a batch file. This took a few steps to get working.

To do so I had to launch a fresh instance of SSVNC. Then I populated all the fields with the necessary information and selected the options I needed in the Options and Advanced Options windows. After that I fetched and saved the SSL certificate. I saved this configuration as a new profile. I then restarted the SSVNC gui and loaded the profile, and most of the settings stuck. The connection was established and the VNC client launched.

To test that I could load it with a profile I opened Command Prompt and navigated to the directory that SSVNC is located. I issued the command "ssvnc.exe demo", demo being my profile name. This launched with (mostly) the correct settings and the SSL connection through the UVNC repeater was made and the VNC client launched fine.

After that, I made my batch file.

```
cd C:...\ssvnc\Windows
start ssvnc.exe demo
```

And this works